# How to set both custom font and textcolor for a same textview in android

Tags: textview, custom-font, android

I have searched a lot in google but i can able to send either one custom font or text in textview but i wanted to set both in the same textview can any one help me in this this my textview

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/pleaseRead"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/pleasereadthis" />*
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use lib @ https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy which provides extensive font capabilities.

Else create font like below

```
 Typeface t = createFromAsset(AssetManager mgr, String path)
```

and then

```
textview.setTypeface(t)
```